# magento system configuration show blank page,

Tags: magento, configuration, system

When i set the **Merge JavaScript Files** and **Merge CSS Files** to "yes" and go **Advanced** closed the following two modules output off

**Mage_AdminNotification**

**Mage_Poll**

The issues arise,magento/system/configuration show blank page right,click on the left of the module not reflect, display is still blank.

Answer (score 0):

Is this issue cause by the merging of js/css or because you disable those modules or both (could you try narrowing it down by disabling one at a time)?

Do you have any js error in your js console (does js work on the regular site)?

Normally if add custom js to your site and dont add semicolon (;) to line ending when you enable merge on your site you will have js error.

Do you have any custom module installed (does the system config work if you enable both)?